# Update & Insert into database using Odata service and linq

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8, wcf-data-services, odata

I am building a windows-phone 8 app that uses a remote database. To access this database I've created a Odata Dataservice (running on IIS).

I have all ready succeeded in retrieving data from the database using this data service. But I want to update and insert data into the database using this service. How do I do that using linq?

note: I have already read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386931.aspx)

But i cant get that link to work with what I allready have:

```
        private void Mainpage_loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 

        var ctx = new MeasurmentEntities(new Uri("http://192.168.11.240:85/NFCDataService.svc/"));
        var coll = new DataServiceCollection<Device>(ctx);

        Lst.ItemsSource = coll;

        coll.LoadCompleted += new EventHandler<LoadCompletedEventArgs>(coll_LoadCompleted);

        var query = from g in ctx.Devices
                    where g.DeviceId > 2
                    orderby g.DeviceName
                    select g;


        coll.LoadAsync(query);

    }

    void coll_LoadCompleted(object sender, LoadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following to add an entity (i.e. insert a record):

```
ctx.AddToDevices(new Device{...});
ctx.BeginSaveChanges(new AsynCallback(r=>{
     DataServiceResponse dsr = ctx.EndSaveChanges(r);
     if (dsr.Any(op => op.Error != null))
     {
       //Show error message
     }
     else
     {
       //Succeeded
     }
},null);
```